# Display the contents of a named range elsewhere in the sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrays

I have a sheet like so:

```
  A B
1 W X
2 Y Z
```

I have the range A1:A2 named as "Column1". I want to display that range elsewhere. Now if I wanted to display it as a row, I know `=TRANSPOSE(Column1)` works. But how can I display it as a column? I know `=TRANSPOSE(TRANSPOSE(Column1))` works, but that's not nice. This seems like a very simple problem, but after a lot of googling it seems that people don't do it. How can this be achieved?

For reference, I want to be able to write, for example, `=FOO(Column1)` in B1 and have the following output:

```
  A B
1 W W
2 Y Y
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the array notation:

```
={Column1}
```

---

This is also useful for combining ranges (if the sizes match): `={ran1, ran2; ran3, ran4}`

Reference: [Using arrays in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en)